# How to add my own key value pair in the metric data (prometheus)?

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager

I have a use-case to setup monitoring system for a fleet of servers.

I was able to do it but, now i have to filter them and show these servers Names instead of server IP's.

I mean the data i get from node_exporter is like this:

ex: up{instance="10.21.88.12:9100",job="node_exporter"}

i want this like:

ex: up{instance="ServerA",job="node_exporter"} (replace 10.21.88.12:9100 with a name "ServerA")

can i do that.

or can i at-least add my own key value pair in the metric data like:

up{instance="10.21.88.12:9100",server_name="ServerA",job="node_exporter"}

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [relabel_config](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config) option.
If you add a key that not exist in the label, it will be added at the label.
if you add a key that exist in the label, it will be updated at the label.

```
relabel_configs:
   - source_labels: [ __address__ ]
     target_label: server_name
     replacement: 'ServerA'
```

If used as above, server_name will be added to the label.

```
relabel_configs:
   - source_labels: [ __address__ ]
     target_label: instance
     replacement: 'ServerA'
```

If used as above, the instance key value in the label will be changed to ServerA.